# How to reroute this downspout?

Tags: drainage, rain, downspout, slope

I am looking for some suggestions on how to best reroute this downspout.  Currently gravity is working it's magic and it is draining downhill following the blue arrow in the images.  The water runs next to the house and pools under the deck beside the house.

The grade is down where the red arrows point.  The trouble is the walkway is right there followed by the garden on a slope.  I am not sure how to get over/under the walkway, and once I do letting the water out on top of the garden will possibly cause erosion.  At the end of the day something will have to give, not sure what the best option may be?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would imagine you need to lift up your path, use buried stormwater piping under your path  and into a buried soak/dry well under your garden.

Comment: So work to dig up concrete etc. You could build a decorative arbor, and run the drain over the top of it.  Something like this http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wYpCXnimEko/VNUtFCvq6SI/AAAAAAAAAjA/QJmLg3fL_s0/s1600/100_5041.JPG

Answer (score 2):

As "D-on" suggested, the best way to go is under the concrete path.  If you feel like replacing the cracked section, then pull it out, dig a trench, and extend the downspout through the trench (ductwork all the way). 
 Alternatively, dig a trench under the concrete and cut a hole directly below the downspout in the existing slab.  The drawback here is you will have trouble fully back-filling the trench after installing the ductwork.

Either way, you should then put in a drywell at the terminus.  Since the piping is below ground level, it can't empty into the garden in any case (unless you run the piping far enough that the ground has sloped down to its level, in which case crushed rock at the exit point will stop erosion)

Comment: I think removing the small section that is cracked and trenching would be the best and easiest. +